# Is this for-loop doing what I think it's doing? Counting consecutive 1's and -1's

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

For a quick backstory: I'm working with temperature data. If it's above a threshold, it's assigned '1'; if below a (separate) threshold, it's '-1'; if it's in between, it's '0'. I want to count above-threshold days and below-threshold days.

```
array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1, -1, -1,  0])
```

I am using the code below to try to count:

```
aok = year['threshold'].values
for i in range(1, len(aok)):
    if aok[i] == 1:
        aok[i] += aok[i - 1]
    if aok[i] == -1:
        aok[i] += aok[i - 1]
```

It results in the following:

```
array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  8,  7,  6,  0])
```

It works fine in the first two rows, counting consecutive 1's and -1's respectively. However, I ran into a problem in the third row, when 1's and -1's were together. **I do not want the -1's and 1's to effect one another.** The following is what I want:

```
array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, -1, -2, -3,  0])
```

Do I need some additional statements in my for-loop to safeguard against the numbers mixing? Something like:

```
    if aok[i] == -1 & aok[i-1] == 1:
        pass
    if aok[i] == 1 & aok[i-1] == -1:
        pass
```

Any help/insight would be appreciated.

Comment: `year['threshold'].groupby(year['threshold'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()).cumsum()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done purely with numpy. Basically we just need to implement a cumulative sum, which resets when a `0` value is hit. First we take the cumsum:

```py
arr = np.array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1, -1, -1,  0])

cms = arr.cumsum()

# array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
#       13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 12, 11, 10,  9,  8,
#       8,  8,  8,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 16, 15, 14, 14])
```

Then we filter `arr` based on `0` values, and we calculate the difference between consecutive elements. This will be the correction for the previous cumsum on those specific items.

```py
correction = np.diff(np.hstack(((0,), cms[arr == 0])))
```

After that, we copy `arr` and apply correction:

```py
arr_copy = np.copy(arr)
arr_copy[arr == 0] -= correction

# array([  0,   0,   0,   0,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,
#          1,   1,   1,   1, -13,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
#          0,   0,   0,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,   5,   0,   0,   0,   1,
#          1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -6])
```

Finally we take the cumsum of `arr_copy` to get the solution:

```py
arr_copy.cumsum()

# array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
#         0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5,
#         0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  8,  7,  6,  0])
```